# Angular Named Router Outlet where parent path is empty

Tags: angular

### Setup:

Version: 5.2.1

### Error Message

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'loginpopup'

This issue appears to be with the following line:

```
this._router.navigate([{ outlets: { login: ['loginpopup'] } }], { relativeTo: this.route });
```

I've tried using the following and still getting no look:

```
this._router.navigate([{ outlets: { login: ['loginpopup'] } }]);

this._router.navigate(['/', { outlets: { login: ['loginpopup'] } }]);

this._router.navigate(['/', '' ,{ outlets: { login: ['loginpopup'] } }]);
```

The issue is related to having a parent path as '' at the root level (See the code below) When changing the path to the shell component to 'anything' and changing the code to:

```
this._router.navigate(['/', 'anything' ,{ outlets: { login: ['loginpopup'] } }]);
```

I'm able to successfully use the named outlet.

### Code

**App.routings.ts**

```
export const appRoutes: Routes =
[
    // Primary Routes
    {
        path: '',
        component: ShellComponent,
        data:
        {
            WebsiteTitle: 'Core'
        },
        children:
        [
            {
                path: 'loginpopup',
                outlet: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent,
                children: [

                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**App.component**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="dialog"></router-outlet>
```

**Shell.component.html**

```
<main class="applicationcontainer m-0 animated fadeIn" [ngClass]="{'mt-5 pt-4': !isLogin}">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
        <router-outlet name="login"></router-outlet>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</main>
```

**Shell.component.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ChangeDetectorRef
} from "@angular/core";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { AutoUnsubscribe } from "ngx-auto-unsubscribe";
import {
  AuthenticationEventService,
  AuthSessionStorageService
} from "interpackages/secure";
import { relative } from "path";

/**
 *
 *
 * @export
 * @class ShellComponent
 */
@Component({
  templateUrl: "shell.component.html",
  selector: "shell",
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ShellComponent {
  public isLogin: boolean = false;

  /**
   *
   * Creates an instance of ShellComponent.
   * @param {Router} _router
   * @param {ChangeDetectorRef} changeRef
   * @memberof ShellComponent
   */
  constructor(
    private _authenticationEventService: AuthenticationEventService,
    private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private _autSessionStorage: AuthSessionStorageService,
    private _router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
    this.isLogin = this._autSessionStorage.AuthenticationInfo.IsSignedIn;
    if (!this.isLogin) {
       this._router.navigate([{ outlets: { login: ['loginpopup'] } }], { relativeTo: this.route });
    } else {
      this._router.navigate(['/', { outlets: { login: null } }]);
    }

    this._authenticationEventService.AuthenticationInfo.subscribe(authUser => {
      this.isLogin = authUser.IsSignedIn;
      if (!authUser.IsSignedIn) {
        this._router.navigate(['/',{ outlets: { login: ['loginpopup'] } }]);
      } else {
        debugger;
        this._router.navigate([{ outlets: { login: null } }]);
      }
      this.changeRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }

  /**
   * For when component is destoried. Also Requied for  AutoUnsubscribe to work on AOT Build
   * @memberof ShellComponent
   * @method ngOnDestory
   *
   */
  ngOnDestroy() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a workaround to angular standards:

The issue relating to empty router outlets. You also need to know that relative paths are only relative to the router tree (ActiveRoutes) and not the URL. With that in mind, I've created a helper function to get around the issue until its fixed in Angular 6.1

```js
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
/**
 *
 * Angular Relative path tempory solution. Angular doesn't like empty paths.
 * Should be fixed in version 6 Pull request 22394
 * https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/22394
 *
 * Angular Issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13011#issuecomment-274414952
 *
 * Before removing check relative paths work on named outlet. Using Navigate on named
 * outlet currently relates to secondary routes (outlet:'route/test)
 * this meant breaking out wasn't possiable using ../../ like documented in
 * angular own documentation
 *
 * key Information: This is relative to routes like anuglar intended NOT URL path
 *
 * Bug only relates to going to parent and down the tree
 *
 * @export NavigateByRelative
 * @param {string} path
 * @param {Router} router
 * @param {ActivatedRoute} route
 *
 */
export function NavigateByRelative(path: string, router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute) {

    /**
     * Relative paths should always start with '../' as per angular documentation
     * https://angular.io/guide/router#relative-navigation
     */
    if (path.startsWith('../')) {
        // split path into multiple paths
        const paths = path.split('/');

        // minus 1 on length as we gurantee need the last index
        const totalPathToLastIndex = paths.length - 1;

        // current index so we can start at this later on
        let currentPathIndex;

        // Relative to is so we get to the correct parent
        let relativeTo = route;

        // Check their is a parent and the current path still intended to go back up the tree
        for (currentPathIndex = 0;
            currentPathIndex < totalPathToLastIndex
            && relativeTo.parent !== undefined
            && paths[currentPathIndex] === '..';
            currentPathIndex++
        ) {
            relativeTo = relativeTo.parent;
        }

        // Navigate starting at the the currentpathIndex and relative to the current parent
        router.navigate([...paths.splice(currentPathIndex )], { relativeTo });

    } else {
        // else use navigation as normal as this should work correctly
        router.navigate([path]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is an open issue in the angular github repository regarding this, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10726

The only work around you can do is to name the base path ie

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [ {
   path: 'myroute', // NO Longer Empty Path
   component: ShellComponent,
   data:  { WebsiteTitle: 'Core' },
   children: [  ...  ]
}];
```